# Run node.js package on web server continuously

Tags: node.js, web-services

I'm using a blog platform [specter](https://github.com/brislink/specter) that starts when I run `npm start`. Only when I have run `npm start` will it show up at the site URL. If I do command-c in the terminal, it quits running the package and the site goes down until i run `npm start` again. Is there some way to set up the server to keep the site up continuously? Right now I have to take down the site before I make any edits and then start it back up with `npm start`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that you can do is to install [Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) by Nodejitsu. What this does is it runs your node script on the background "forever" or until you  stop the process or set a timeout limit.

To install Forever, just do:

```
npm install forever -g
```

For your case, you will want to cd into the directory that Specter resides and start forever:

```
cd $(specterLocation)
forever start server.js
```

This will start your server on the background until you do:

```
forever stop server.js (in directory of Specter)
forever stopall (wherever on server)
```

To see the list of processes started by Forever, just use:

```
forever list
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was confused because before I was starting up the server by using `npm start` but I didn't realize I could achieve the same thing with `node server.js`, which is what running `forever start server.js` does in the background.

Comment: Yup! What `npm start` does is it looks for the package.json file and if there is a start function listed, it will run that.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon)

It will auto-restart your node application whenever it detects changes to the directory where nodemon was started.

It is available as an npm package as well (https://npmjs.org/package/nodemon).

Comment: The only problem with this strategy is that it doesn't allow you to save your code in an interim state.  Either you start and complete your edits, then save (and nodemon will restart for you), or you start, save, nodemon restarts and your app breaks, you keep working and nodemon keeps trying until you bring your app back to a stable state.  This is a good argument against doing development on your production code, but that appears to be how the OP is working, and if all he's ever going to be working on is his small personal blog, is good enough.

Comment: Ah, I glossed over the fact that he's doing this on production code.

Answer (score 1):

Just make your edits with the site running.  Then when you're done, stop the site and start it back up.  The site isn't continually running from the files, it starts up, loads into memory, then runs from there, releasing it's hold on the files.

Or, there are any number of more robust management strategies you could implement, complete with version control, process managers, integration strategies...  If you plan on growing your skills to support high volume or commercial implementations, then you should look into these things.  If you're just running your personal blog and that's it, just edit your files, then restart your server process when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Use Node Supervisor. It's really easy to use and install.

```
npm install supervisor -g
```

run with

```
supervisor whateverFileYouWant.js
```

https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor